# Android Bluetooth Background Service

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, spp

I have an Android Device and i try to use it with an Arduino via Bluetooth. I managed to do that using Google BluetoothChat example. The problem is that i setup the connection in Activity1 and I want to send data and receive data in Activity2. So i searched a bit and i found out that i need a service for that. I fond this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038770/4588648) but i don't understand what `AbstractActivity` needs to contain and what `MyAplication` class should contain or what class is that. The one i setup connection from?

Can you explain it to me? I can't ask on that topic because i don't have 50 reputation.

Thank!