# Connect Bluetooth on Android Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I found a sample code for manage connection on service. But I don't know how use it.

I only write here the code that I don't understand, to see all the code:

[Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025852/how-to-move-bluetooth-activity-into-a-service)

**CODE**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("popopo", "Onstart Command");
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        deviceName = device.getName();
        String macAddress = device.getAddress();
        if (macAddress != null && macAddress.length() > 0) {
            connectToDevice(macAddress);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    String stopservice = intent.getStringExtra("stopservice");
    if (stopservice != null && stopservice.length() > 0) {
        stop();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I connect correcly to bluetooth without service, getting device with this code:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
}
```

My question is: How to pass my found Bluetooth device ID when `onStartCommand()`  gonna executed?

Which Bluetooth Device it's trying to connect when I don't executed ACTION_FOUND?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late, but just in case. If I recall correctly, there are a number of ways you can go to connect to a device, given its mac address.

- Pass the device's address as an extra in the creation intent.

  **In UI Activity**

  ```
  Intent intent=new Intent(this,BluetoothService.class));
  intent.putExtra("DEVICE_ADDRESS",device.getAddress());

  startService(intent);
  ```

  **In Bluetooth service**

  ```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      String address = intent.getExtras("DEVICE_ADDRESS");

      ###DO SOMETHING WITH ADDRESS HERE###
  }
  ```
- Create a 'connectToDevice(String address)' method in your service, and call it from wherever you have your BroadcastReceiver.

  **In Bluetooth service**

  ```
  protected synchronized void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device){//Cancells any threads attempting to connect and starts a new connectThread (new connection)

      if (mConnectThread != null) {
          mConnectThread.cancel();
          mConnectThread = null;
          Log.d(TAG,"Cancelled connectThread");
      }


      if (mConnectedThread != null) {
          mConnectedThread.cancel();
          mConnectedThread = null;
          Log.d(TAG,"Cancelled connectedThread");

      }

      mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
      mConnectThread.start();
      Log.d(TAG,"Starting connectThread");
  }
  ```

  **In Broadcast receiver**

  ```
  if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
      mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
      BluetoothService mBluetoothService = new BluetoothService();
      mBluetoothService.connectToDevice(device.getAddress());

  }
  ```

You should check out the [BluetoothChat example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) offered by android. I think it shows a lot of tings you'll need.