# Connect to a bluetooth device using stored MAC address through service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, bluetooth, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android and I am trying to understand the working of Bluetooth connection. For that I have used used the wiced sense app to understand the working.

Here I want to connect to a particular device with respect to their MAC address. I have managed to store and retrieve the MAC address through Shared preferences. And now I want to connect to device which matches the MAC address without user interaction.

To store the MAC address I do the following:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name) == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.devicepicker_listitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            String DeviceName;

            holder.device_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
          //  DeviceName= String.valueOf((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name));
            holder.device_addr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_addr);
            holder.device_rssi = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_rssi);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DeviceRecord rec = mDevices.get(position);
        holder.device_rssi.setProgress(normaliseRssi(rec.rssi));
        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String deviceName = rec.device.getName();
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0) {
            holder.device_name.setText(rec.device.getName());
            holder.device_addr.setText(rec.device.getAddress());
            //Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
            if(deviceName.equals("eVulate")&& !editor.contains("MAC_ID")) {
                storeMacAddr(String.valueOf(rec.device.getAddress()));
               }
        } else {
            holder.device_name.setText(rec.device.getAddress());
            holder.device_addr.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_device));
        }

        return convertView;

 public void storeMacAddr(String MacAddr) {

        editor.edit().putString("MAC_ID", MacAddr).commit();
    }
        }
```

I retrive the same through the following code :

```
private void initDevicePicker() {           
        final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       if(mSharedPreference.contains("MAC_ID")){
        String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("MAC_ID", ""));
        }
        else
          // search for devices
}
```

I want to start a service after retrieving the MAC address and I don't know where exactly to do that. 
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I saw one of the answer which suits to my situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025852/how-to-move-bluetooth-activity-into-a-service) . If anyone can provide me some more details especially with MyApplication and Abstract class it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

All you have the MAC addresses of some bluetooth devices and you want to connect to them using their MAC addresses. I think you need to read more about bluetooth discovery and connection but anyway, I'm putting some code which might help you later after reading about Android bluetooth.

From your `Activity` you need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` so identify the bluetooth connection changes and to start discovering nearby bluetooth devices. The `BroadcastReceiver` will look like this

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (device.getAddress().equals(Constants.DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                startCommunication(device);
            }

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {


        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Your bluetooth device is connected to the Android bluetooth

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Your device is disconnected. Try connecting again via startDiscovery
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    }
};
```

There's a `startCommunication` function inside I'll post it later in this answer. Now you need to register this `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity.

Inside your `onCreate` register the receiver like this

```
// Register bluetooth receiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Don't forget to `unregister` the receiver inside `onDestroy` function of your `Activity`

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Now in your `Activity` you need to declare a `BluetoothAdapter` to start bluetooth discovery and a `BluetoothSocket` to make connection with the bluetooth. So you need to add these two variables in your `Activity` and initialize them accordingly.

```
// Declaration
public static BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
```

...

```
// Inside `onCreate` initialize the bluetooth adapter and start discovering nearby BT devices
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Now here you go for the `startCommunication` function

```
void startCommunication(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.execute((Void) null);
    }
}
```

The `ConnectThread` is an `AsyncTask` which connects to a desired device in a different thread and opens a `BluetoothSocket` for communication.

```
public class ConnectThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private BluetoothDevice btDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.btDevice = device;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            YourActivity.mmSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Constants.MY_UUID);
            YourActivity.mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            YourActivity.mmSocket.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

        if (result != null){/* Success */}
        else {/* Connection Failed */}

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {}

}
```

This is how you can find the nearby bluetooth device and connect to them by using the MAC addresses stored previously.

Comment: Thank you fro the information. But, I want to include the bluetooth connectivity in a service. I do this because once the app gets disconnected the service should start running and search for the device with MAC address and then connect to it(If available). How do I implement the above code in a service.?

Answer (score -1):

After `String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("MAC_ID", ""));` you can start service. [Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#connect) all thing that you required for Getting data and send data to Bluetooth device.

Comment: This question is not subjected to BLE. So please update your answer or remove it

Comment: @ReazMurshed Read question it is subjected to Bluetooth connection.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Anyway, the question is about bluetooth connection - YES! There's a basic difference between bluetooth and BLE. And please, mention some working codes whenever you answer a question in SO.