# How to use Handler and handleMessage in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-handler

Java code:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       // code here
    }
};
```

How to convert this java code to Kotlin?

I tried this:

```
private val mHandler = object : Handler() {
    fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
       // code here
    }
}
```

But this is seems to be incorrect and gives a compile time error on `object`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Problem:** The syntax to override `handleMessage()` method of the `Handler` class is incorrect.

**Solution:** Add `override` keyword before the function that you want to override.

```
private val mHandler = object : Handler() {

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
        // Your logic code here.
    }
}
```

**Update:** As @BeniBela's comment, when using above code, a lint warning will be displayed

> This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur.
>
> Since this Handler is declared as an inner class, it may prevent the
>   outer class from being garbage collected. If the Handler is using a
>   Looper or MessageQueue for a thread other than the main thread, then
>   there is no issue.
>
> If the Handler is using the Looper or MessageQueue of the main thread,
>   you need to fix your Handler declaration, as follows: Declare the
>   Handler as a static class; In the outer class, instantiate a
>   WeakReference to the outer class and pass this object to your Handler
>   when you instantiate the Handler; Make all references to members of
>   the outer class using the WeakReference object.

```
class OuterClass {

    // In the outer class, instantiate a WeakReference to the outer class.
    private val outerClass = WeakReference<OuterClass>(this)

    // Pass the WeakReference object to the outer class to your Handler
    // when you instantiate the Handler
    private val mMyHandler = MyHandler(outerClass)

    private var outerVariable: String = "OuterClass"

    private fun outerMethod() {

    }

    // Declare the Handler as a static class.
    class MyHandler(private val outerClass: WeakReference<OuterClass>) : Handler() {

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            // Your logic code here.
            // ...

            // Make all references to members of the outer class 
            // using the WeakReference object.
            outerClass.get()?.outerVariable
            outerClass.get()?.outerMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives a HandlerLeak lint warning

Comment: @BeniBela thanks for your info, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 16):

You may do it a bit easier (without WeakReference) by passing looper to handler:

```
val handler = object:  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            doStuff()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case :

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private inner class MessageHandler(private val mContext: Context) : Handler() {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            when (msg.what) {

            }
        }
    }
```