# Cannot override handleMessage when creating new Handler with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025302/10002144).

This is how I expect to be able to create a new `Handler` and override the `handleMessage()` function without having to declare it as a new class:

```
val handler = Handler {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {

    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work and gives me two errors:

1. `Modifier 'override' is not applicable to local function`
2. `Expected a value of type Boolean`

How exactly can I just create a new `Handler` and override the `handleMessage()` function without having to declare a new class?

Answer (score 2):

Make the instance using **object Expressions**. This will let you override all the class methods.

Read more about this [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)

Replace your code with this.

```
 val handler = object : Handler() {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your code gives me a warning "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur". Is this something that can cause an issue?

Comment: No, it is fine.